# Best way to install anaconda if you already have jupyter lab

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas, jupyter-lab

A while ago, I installed jupyter lab and I use it a lot.

I also use python a lot via VScode.

But I have had problems in the past when doing a new type of python install and losing access to other ways of using python.

I now need to install geopandas both which strongly recommends installing with anaconda/conda. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html

Anyone got any advice on the best way to do this on windows without destabilising either jupyter labs or python in VScode.

Should I uninstall jupyter labs first?

Answer (score 1):

You can run standard Python and Anaconda in parallel w/o any trouble. Just make sure you stick to the default installation options and you **don't add Anaconda's Python to the system path**

However, you will only be able to use Anaconda's Python after activating an environment with the command

```
conda activate
```

Besides that, consider running your [Jupyter Notebook within VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks). It's way more convenient that Jupyter Lab ...

Comment: Thank you for the good advice. I have transitioned to Jupyter within VScode and it's great as you say.  Any special advice on unstalling jupyter labs?